# Which technology choice/programming language for building a Windows Phone 8 puzzle game?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

I'm not sure of which technology choice to approach building a simple puzzle game. I'd like to  build an "engine" that will let me select areas of an image as "puzzle pieces" and put them in a box for the child to select and drag to the puzzle grid. I'm not sure of where to start for WP8 as I've never built anything with XNA, and C++ is beyond me at my current level.

Which programming language and technology would I need to use to accomplish this type of functionality? Can this be done without Native C++ code in WP8, or would it require XNA/C++?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: You shouldn't have any trouble doing this entirely in XNA / C#.  Also this question is a bit off topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think XNA would be up to the task and is supported in WP8.

However, in the event you want to port the game (or "future proof") to Windows Store ("Metro"), you may want to take a look at MonoGame, or more explicit DirectX with SharpDX.